# woocommerce empty product name field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce 2.3.8 and WordPress 4.2.1. Is there a way to remove the product title from an individual product? I used to be able to just put a blank space and the product title would be blank, but now it doesn't let me, it just keeps putting the original product title back in when I update the product. This is only for one category of products. I would like to have a category page of products that have no titles, just the featured images in a grid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Dirty Solution

Use CSS:
All of your list items for a product on a category have css classes named after the categories' name e.g. `product_cat-mycatgegory`.
You can find the product's title within an `<h3>` element.

Therefore the following CSS Code would prevent displaying the product's title on the category page.

```
.product_cat-mycatgegory h3{
    display:none;
}
```

Note that the product title is be still readable via the browser's inspector.

## 2. Cleaner Solution

You could edit the `content-product.php` template. Check if a current category is chosen and decide whether to show the title or not. Please check [woocommerce's documentation about template structure and overriding](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

> Pseudocode

```
<?php

$cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$category_ID  = $cat_obj->term_id;

if(!($category_ID == category_ID_without_titles)) :?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: You won't lose your edits if you [override the template](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) in your own theme, which is how WooCommerce is designed to be used. Additionally, you could probably use [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) as your conditional logic.

Comment: Thank you, the CSS solution worked perfectly.  The template override solution didn't work, it made the title appear twice. I may have coded incorrectly.